# Getting identifier error while trying to use Classes

Tags: c++, class, object, identifier

I am attempting to make an interactive loop that will only break when the user inputs EOF.

When I run the program and it runs the code in main() it spits out the error

> error C3861: 'startClass': identifier not found

I've declared startClass in the public class as well as outside the main in its own function so not sure what identifier cannot be found. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ExchangeList {
private:
    double exchRate;

public:
    ExchangeList() {
        exchRate = 0;
    }

    void AddExchange(double x) {
        if (x > 0) {
            exchRate = x;
        }
    }

    double getExchange() {
        return exchRate;
    }

    void startClass(double, double, double, string, string);

};


int main() {
    double value{ 0 };
    double exchange{ 0 };
    double transaction{ 0 };
    string toCurr;
    string fromCurr;
    //ExchangeList N;

    while (!cin.eof()) {
        cout << "Input exchange rate: ";
        cin >> exchange;
        startClass(value, exchange, transaction, toCurr, fromCurr);   
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void startClass(double value, double exchange, double transaction, string toCurr, string fromCurr) {
    ExchangeList N;

    N.AddExchange(exchange);
    cout << N.getExchange();
    return;

}
```

Comment: You declared `startClass` as a member of `ExchangeList` but are trying to use it as a free function

Comment: See [why `while (!cin.eof())` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539).

Comment: `startClass()` is a non-static member of `ExchangeList`, so it can only be called on an object, not as a freestanding function. You might want to review how class member functions work in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems here:

### cin::eof()

It is a mistake to use this function, it will be better to find something else to end the while loop. Somthing like a specific input that will indicate that the loop is over, try something like this:

```
cout << "Input exchange rate: ";
cin >> exchange;
while (exchange != -9999) {
    startClass(value, exchange, transaction, toCurr, fromCurr); 
    cout << "Input exchange rate: ";
    cin >> exchange;
}
```

### Declaration of the function, above the main

You created a function without class `startClass`, without declaration above the `main` function, what cause that the `main` function can't use this function.

```
void startClass(double value, double exchange, double transaction, string toCurr, string fromCurr);

int main() {
...
//use the function...
...
}

void startClass(double value, double exchange, double transaction, string toCurr, string fromCurr) {
        ...
}
```

Or, withou declaration- definition above the main:

```
void startClass(double value, double exchange, double transaction, string toCurr, string fromCurr) {
        ...
}

int main() {
...
//use the function...
...
}
```

### Make the function belong to the class

You tried to declare a class's function `startClass`, but in the definition you didn't specified the class name, like this:

```
void ExchangeList::startClass(double value, double exchange, double transaction, string toCurr, string fromCurr) {
    AddExchange(exchange);
    cout << getExchange();
    return;
}
```

### In case of class's function

When you call the function of the class, you didn't specified the class of the function:

```
class ExchangeList {
    ...
public:
    void startClass(double, double, double, string, string);
};

void ExchangeList::startClass(double value, double exchange, double transaction, string toCurr, string fromCurr) {
    AddExchange(exchange);
    cout << getExchange();
    return;

}

int main() {
    ...
    ExchangeList N;

    while (exchange != -9999) {
        ...
        N.startClass(value, exchange, transaction, toCurr, fromCurr);   
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Static function inside the class

```
class ExchangeList {
    ...
public:
    static void startClass(double, double, double, string, string);
};

int main() {
    ...    
    while (exchange != -9999) {
        ...
        ExchangeList::startClass(value, exchange, transaction, toCurr, fromCurr);   
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void ExchangeList::startClass(double value, double exchange, double transaction, string toCurr, string fromCurr) {
    ExchangeList N;

    N.AddExchange(exchange);
    cout << N.getExchange();
    return;

}
```

Comment: I doubt that `void ExchangeList::startClass(double value, double exchange, double transaction, string toCurr, string fromCurr) {
    ExchangeList N;` is something that the OP is looking for. Seems more like OP'd like to make that a friend function.

Comment: There are so many ways to solve this problem, I am just trying to mention most of them in this comment, so the publisher can use the one that he feel more comfortable with.

Comment: What you call a "pre-declaration" is simply called a "declaration", and the implementation is called a "definition". `this.some_member` doesn't compile, and there is no point in writing `this->` every time you access a member. There's also much nicer ways to read to the end of the file other than using some special value.